# Counting the occurrences of a value in one array that appear in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of people that looks like this:

```
$people =
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => NameSurname@example.com
                [name] => Name Surname
                [count] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => Name2Surname@example.com
                [name] => Name2 Surname
                [count] => 0
            )
    )
```

And I have an array which is the result of a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
$query=
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => NameSurname@example.com
                [name] => Name Surname
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => Name2Surname@example.com
                [name] => Name2 Surname
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [email] => NameSurname@example.com
                [name] => Name Surname
            )

    )
```

For each e-mail address in $people, I'd like `$people['count']` to equal how many times that e-mail address occurs in $query.

I've tried loads of ways to do this, and I'm not quite getting the desired result.

For the avoidance of doubt, my end result based on the example above should look like:

```
$people =
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => NameSurname@example.com
                [name] => Name Surname
                [count] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => Name2Surname@example.com
                [name] => Name2 Surname
                [count] => 1
            )
    )
```

Comment: where is your code for checking the duplicate values.

Comment: Can you select counted emails from database directly? Somthing like this:
`SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE email IN ('NameSurname@example.com', 'Name2Surname@example.com') GROUP BY email`?

Comment: I see what you're both saying, but neither are useful in this particular case. The arrays actually contain lots more information than shown above therefore, duplicate values aren't an issue. As for the MySQL query, each array could contain hundreds of items so any extra queries isn't optimal. Thank you for taking the time to comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($people as $key => $man) { // iterating through each man
  $_occurences = 0;

  foreach ($query as $_item) // iterating through each result in the result set
    if ($_item['email'] == $man['email']) // comparing current man to each result item
      $_occurences ++;

  $people[$key]['count'] = $_occurences; // saving number of occurrences in the `count` key 

 }
```

---

**UPD:** One more solution using `array_map`, `array_reduce` and nice `ternary` operator. Its slower than one with `foreach`, but twice as compact and professional.

It is slower (*in terms of performance*) bec. of function calls overhead, but on "small" amount of iterations this drop is negligible. It will update `$people` array without reassigning it bec. we transmitted each `&$man` by reference.

```
array_map(function (&$man) use ($query) {
    $man['count'] = array_reduce($query, function ($count, $row) use ($man) {
        return ($row['email'] === $man['email']) ? ++$count : $count ;
    }, 0);
}, $people);
```

Comment: That's it - thank you so much. Got the answer I needed quickly and learnt something new for next time. Well done, and thank you for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's exactly what you need., but you can change the query you are running to:

```
SELECT COUNT(name) as cnt, name,email FROM table_name GROUP BY name;
```

and then `$query` array will look like:

```
$query=
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [email] => NameSurname@example.com
                [name] => Name Surname
                [cnt] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [email] => Name2Surname@example.com
                [name] => Name2 Surname
                [cnt] => 1
            )                  
    )
```

and then you can run on the arrays and just get the `cnt` of each item in the `$query` array.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Was looking for a more PHP way of doing this and @Paul T. Rawkeen got the solution I was hoping for.